# Limit folder size on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I do have a file server on Windows server 2008 and I am trying to limit the size of each folder as 2GB. What is the best way to do it? I have two types of users which are connected as an Active Directory users and connected through "Map Network Drive".

Answer (score 1):

Disk Quotas are probably what you want.

Here a [LINK](http://www.petri.co.il/managing-windows-server-2008-disk-quotas.htm) on setting them up.